# Hagoromo Otsutsuki reincarnation

Tags: naruto, boruto

The question is derived from Suigetsu's dialog to Mitsuki in *Boruto: Naruto Next Generations* episode 30.

> Boruto is your *sun*, isn't he?

We both see the sun and the moon has been associated with Hagoromo and Hamura Otsutsuki. They can be reincarnated since both are dead, and Naruto and Sasuke are reincarnations of Indra and Asura respectively.

Is this possible?

Comment: Indra and Asura had reasons to reincarnate - Hagaromo and Hamura don't...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Boruto is your sun, isn't he?

This dialogue is a figure of speech. Here Boruto is *Mitsuki's* sun, meaning, he brightens up Mitsuki's day. Or to put it simply, Boruto brings joy to him. The context of the scene is crucial.

Next, the Otsutsuki brothers do not reincarnate. Indra reincarnated to fulfill his mission of a perfect world, under his reign. Ashura reincarnated to stop Indra and save him from the blindness, with his love. Hagaromo entrusted Ashura with Ninshu, thereby clearing all his goals. Whereas Hamura entrusted his will to his clan. Both had no reasons to be reincarnated.

---

Here's a much more detailed answer from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Boruto/comments/6hvnw1/boruto_is_mitsukis_sun_to_his_moon/) (credits to @Wondercricket):

> In Naruto Gaiden: The Road Illuminated by the Full Moon we get to see a bit more of Mitsuki's backstory and how he is related to Orochimaru, as well as how he is different from Orochimaru. Orochimaru runs the same test on Mitsuki several times, wiping his memory each time it fails. The test revolves around Mitsuki gaining 2 options, if he chooses either, he fails. He only succeeds upon finding a 3rd option for himself.
>
> When he does this, he is rewarded with information about Boruto. Whom he, at that time, decides that Boruto is his "sun". His "light" in the darkness that will shine a bright future for him if he is to follow him. Hence, he holds respect for Boruto as well as hope.

Comment: Was going to post answer, but there is also a [one-shot manga](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Gaiden:_The_Road_Illuminated_by_the_Full_Moon) with some backstory to Mitsuki and why the "sun" is important to him. (Credits to users on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Boruto/comments/6hvnw1/boruto_is_mitsukis_sun_to_his_moon/))

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I wasn't aware that the OP was referring to the one shot.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP is referring to the one shot, since the context of the question is in the Anime, but it definitely shines light on the question

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Damn I wanted my theory to be true so bad!! Thanks for the answer! This makes more sense!